# ubuntu: start (upstart) second instance of mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, daemon, upstart

the standard upstart script that comes with mongodb works fine:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb.conf

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGODB="yes"
  if [ -f /etc/default/mongodb ]; then . /etc/default/mongodb; fi
  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf; fi
end script
```

if i want to run a second instance of mongod i thought i just copy both `/etc/mongodb.conf` -> `/etc/mongodb2.conf` and `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` -> `/etc/init/mongodb2.conf` and change the std port in the first conf-file. then adjust the script above to start with the newly created `/etc/mongodb2.conf`.

i can then just say `start mongodb2`and the service starts ... but it is killed right after starting. what do i change, to get both processes up and running?

```
 # Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb2.conf

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb2/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb2/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGODB="yes"
  if [ -f /etc/default/mongodb ]; then . /etc/default/mongodb; fi
  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb2.conf; fi
end script
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i couldn't get the "standard" upstart script to work (as described above), so i changed it like this:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb.conf

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script

  exec sudo -u mongodb /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

end script
```

and if you want to run other instances of mongodb just copy the *.conf files and make the changes to `/etc/mongodb2.conf` and `/etc/init/mongodb2.conf`

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb2.conf

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb2/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb2/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script

  exec sudo -u mongodb /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb2.conf

end script
```

i think the only thing that is not working is `restart mongodb` - you have to `stop` and then `start` again ...

Answer (score 5):

I know there's already an accepted solution but I think this one is more elegant.

The other way is to use start-stop-daemon's pid file creation.  For example, I have 2 mongos running on the same server with 2 different upstart scripts, and the two magic lines are:

```
exec start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/mongodb-router.pid --start --startas /data/bin/mongos --chuid mongo -- --logappend --logpath /mnt/log/mongos.log --configdb mongo2-config01,mongo2-config02,mongo2-config03


exec start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/mongodb-routerrt.pid --start --startas /data/bin/mongos --chuid mongo -- --logappend --logpath /mnt/log/mongos-rt.log --configdb mongort-config01,mongort-config02,mongort-config03 --port 27027
```

Note that one has '--pidfile /var/run/mongodb-router.pid' and the other has '--pidfile /var/run/mongodb-routerrt.pid' and a different port.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I ran into this same issue today.  The reason is that the default script uses the start-stop-daemon to start mongo, which is specifically designed to ensure that only one version of a process is running.  You already figured out that one way to fix this is to not use start-stop-daemon and to start the binary yourself.  That's the way I do it too but I'd be curious to hear if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.
2 instances of mongodb, with start-stop-daemon, on the same server

that are my start-stop-daemon configs

```
exec start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/lib/mongodb/db1.pid --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --name mongod1 --exec /usr/bin/mongod -- --config etc/mongodb1.conf

exec start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/lib/mongodb/db2.pid --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --name mongod2 --exec /usr/bin/mongod -- --config etc/mongodb2.conf
```

pay attention to the `--name` option. That did the trick for me

Comment: Upstart was not allowing me to start and stop my multiple mongod's until I added the `--name` parameter, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the two daemons cannot listen on the same tcp port, thus you have to change the --port parameter of mongod2 in order to listen to a different port.
the two daemons cannot share the same data dir, thus you have to change the --data-dir parameter of mongod2.

Comment: yes, i know. that's why i copied the `/etc/mongodb2.conf` and changed the port and data-folder (as i wrote above). but still not working ...

Comment: sorry, but you haven't posted your config file, so i guessed.  what happens if you start the second daemon by hand via console and not a daemon, which is the cause of the premature exit?

Comment: it works when i call `mongod --config /etc/mognodb2.conf` by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I find the below upstart works for me

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb.conf

description "manage mongodb instance"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

env MONGODB_USER=mongodb
env MONGODB_DATA=/var/lib/mongodb/
env MONGODB_LOG=/var/log/mongodb/
env MONGODB_PID=/var/run/mongodb.pid

pre-start script
  if [ ! -d $MONGODB_DATA ]; then
    mkdir -p $MONGODB_DATA
    chown $MONGODB_USER:$MONGODB_USER $MONGODB_DATA
  fi

  if [ ! -d $MONGODB_LOG ]; then
    mkdir -p $MONGODB_LOG
    chown $MONGODB_USER:$MOGODB_USER $MONGODB_LOG
  fi
end script

exec start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $MONGODB_PID --chuid $MONGODB_USER:$MONGODB_USER --exec /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf

pre-stop exec start-stop-daemon --signal QUIT --stop --quiet --pidfile $MONGODB_PID --chuid $MONGODB_USER:$MONGODB_USER --exec /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf
```